# match whole word only without regex

Tags: php, regex, strpos

Since i cant use preg_match (UTF8 support is somehow broken, it works locally but breaks at production) i want to find another way to match word against blacklist. Problem is, i want to search a string for exact match only, not first occurrence of the string.

This is how i do it with preg_match

```
preg_match('/\b(badword)\b/', strtolower($string));
```

Example string:

```
$string = "This is a string containing badwords and one badword";
```

I want to only match the "badword" (at the end) and not "badwords".

```
strpos('badword', $string) matches the first one
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Split the string on spaces and check each word against your blacklist

Comment: @jonhopkins That won't work for punctuation (assuming there's going to be some).

Comment: True.. Didn't think of that. Surely there's a way to strip punctuation though?

Comment: How exactly it breaks at production? Which is your PHP version and which is the PHP version of the production server?

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos it just doesnt match, i ended up using mb_ereg instead of preg_match - did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you could do some pre-processing, you could use replace all your punctuation marks with white spaces and put everything in lowercase and then either:

- Use `strpos` with something like so `strpos(' badword ', $string)` in a while loop to keep on iterating through your entire document;
- Split the string at white spaces and compare each word with a list of bad words you have.

So if you where trying the first option, it would something like so (untested pseudo code)

```
$documet = body of text to process . ' ' 
$document.replace('!@#$%^&*(),./...', ' ')
$document.toLowerCase()
$arr_badWords = [...]
foreach($word in badwords)
{
    $badwordIndex = strpos(' ' . $word . ' ', $document)
    while(!badWordIndex)
    {
        //
        $badwordIndex = strpos($word, $document)
    }
}
```

EDIT: As per @jonhopkins suggestion, adding a white space at the end should cater for the scenario where there wanted word is at the end of the document and is not proceeded by a punctuation mark.

Comment: What if the bad word is the very first word in the document, or the last word and there was no punctuation after it? I don't think this would match it. But would it be acceptable to add a space to the beginning and end of `$document` just to be sure?

Comment: @jonhopkins: I agree. Ammended the answer as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mimic the `\b` modifier of regex you can try something like this:

```
$offset = 0;
$word = 'badword';
$matched = array();
while(($pos = strpos($string, $word, $offset)) !== false) {
    $leftBoundary = false;
    // If is the first char, it has a boundary on the right
    if ($pos === 0) {
       $leftBoundary = true;
    // Else, if it is on the middle of the string, we must check the previous char
    } elseif ($pos > 0 && in_array($string[$pos-1], array(' ', '-',...)) {
        $leftBoundary = true;
    }

    $rightBoundary = false;
    // If is the last char, it has a boundary on the right
    if ($pos === (strlen($string) - 1)) {
       $rightBoundary = true;
    // Else, if it is on the middle of the string, we must check the next char
    } elseif ($pos < (strlen($string) - 1) && in_array($string[$pos+1], array(' ', '-',...)) {
        $rightBoundary = true;
    }

    // If it has both boundaries, we add the index to the matched ones...
    if ($leftBoundary && $rightBoundary) {
        $matched[] = $pos;
    }

    $offset = $pos + strlen($word);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`strrpos()`](http://php.net/strrpos) instead of [`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos):

> strrpos — Find the position of the last occurrence of a substring in a string

```
$string = "This is a string containing badwords and one badword";
var_dump(strrpos($string, 'badword'));
```

Output:

```
45
```

Comment: This assumes that the string is known by the programmer. If the string is being retrieved from user input, it's possible the blacklisted word could come before another word that would be matched, so this doesn't necessarily work for anything but the test-case above.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to use word boundaries with unicode properties:

```
preg_match('/(?:^|[^pL\pN_])(badword)(?:[^pL\pN_]|$)/u', $string);
```

In fact it's much more complicated, have a look at **[here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/)**.